# Django: Why does a POST to UpdateView silently fail?

Tags: django

I've had a couple of occasions where I have introduced a very annoying bug into my Django site.  I'm using Class Based Views (CBV), and I caused CreateView and UpdateView to silently fail.  The repro steps for, say, the CreateView problem are:

1. Enter a URL into the browser to display the CreateView-related form
2. Enter the form data
3. Click the submit button
4. The completed form re-appears but no object is created - Django doesn't go to the URL in the model's get_absolute_url(...) function

```
# views.py snippet

class ListingUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Listing
    fields = ['orig', 'dest', 'container_type_code', 'container_bic_owner',
              'container_max_kg', 'ship_imo', 'ship_owner_imo',
              'ship_embarkation', 'ship_sailing', 'ship_docking', 'ship_unloaded',
              'reserve_price', 'buy_now_price', 'currency', 'stage']
```

```
# listing_form.html snippet

                <div class="col-4" style="padding-left: 0; display: inline; float: left;">
                    {{ form.orig|as_crispy_field }}
                </div>
                <div class="col-4" style=" display: inline; float: left;">
                    {{ form.dest|as_crispy_field }}
                </div>
                <div class="col-4" style=" display: inline; float: left;">
                    {{ form.container_type_code|as_crispy_field }}
                </div>
```

As you can see, I render individual fields rather than render the whole form with one tag.

Comment: can you please share urlpatterns and model in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hadn't realised this got posted - it seemed to fail when I posted the question. I had intended to answer it myself.

The cause of the problem is a mismatch between the fields in the ListingUpdateView class and the fields on the template.  The fields list includes a field called stage but I had not included this in the listing_form.html template.  That simple error causes the silentfailure.